# How do I get permission to access my own extensions resources (a specific page)?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Due to recent changes in the Chrome API, my plugin issues this error:

> Error during tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url
>   "chrome-extension://ecfgljdfndkhhbmhcnelbpnhkflgiokp/cm_signature_editor.html".
>   Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.

This never used to be the case. Now I wonder how I get the URL of the chrome extension into it's manifest file:

I know I can get the url or a resource within my extension like so:

`chrome.extension.getURL('/manifest.json')`

But I don't know how that can work in the manifest file.

Is there another way to get this code working?

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code:function_to_execute}, function() {
    // callback
});
```

What's interesting is that even when I hardcode the chrome URL it doesn't work (I get the same error)

```
"permissions" : [
    "tabs",
    "contextMenus",
    "chrome-extension://ecfgljdfndkhhbmhcnelbpnhkflgiokp/*"
  ],
```

Comment: Which manifest version do you use - 1 or 2?

Comment: not specifying, but I assume first.

Comment: switching to manifest version 2 gives me this error: `Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.`

Comment: I fixed most other bugs due to the API change, but the original questions still remains un-answered.

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem right now. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cant inject a script in a extension page in that way.
You should incorporate the script in the page just by writing it in you extension HTML file.
And make comunications between extension pages using chrome.extension.sendRequest and  chrome.extension.onRequest

Answer (score 1):

Using `chrome.extension.getViews()` may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem, below is what I did,

- For the script, created a separate js and attached it to the page on which executeScript was being done.
- For the data, set it in the localstorage and accessed it in the above newly created js file

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I know what is your problem ;) There are two ways to inject content script in `chrome.tabs.executeScript`:

- code string - works similar to `eval`
- filename - so if you want to execute js file you have in your extension directory, just pass its name `{file: 'js/script.js'}`

In addition you have to add proper site host in manifest permissions field, e.g. if you want to execute content script in `http://example.com/page.html` add `example.com` host